# When navigating to a single project page I get a type error

Tags: gatsby

trying to render a single page project file in GatsbyJS, however got an error:

UPDATE: cleared cache and restarted mac. Got the following error.

I have not added the class with the name `gatsby-focus-wrapper` anywhere in code.

[image]

Plus when I make some minor changes to  any `.scss` file, I get the element type error:

[image]

filestructure:

`src/templates/project.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../styles/Layout.scss'
import Head from '../components/Head'
import Project from '../components/Project'

export const query = graphql`
    query($slug: String!) {
        projectsJson(slug: { eq: $slug}) {
        title
        description
        url 
        image {
            childImageSharp {
            fluid {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                  }
               }
            }
        }
    }
`;
const ProjectTemplate = ({ data }) => {
    const project = data.projectsJson;
    const title = project.title;
    const description = project.description;
    const imageData = project.image.childImageSharp.fluid; 
    const url = project.url;

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head title={project.title}/>
            <Project
            title={title}
            description={description}
            imageData={imageData}
            url={url}
            />
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default ProjectTemplate
```

`src/pages/projects.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import Head from '../components/Head'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import ProjectPreview from "../components/Project-preview"


const Project = () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
        allProjectsJson {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            slug
            description
            image {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const projects = data.allProjectsJson.edges;

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Head title="projects"/>
          <div id="portfolio">
          {projects.map(({ node: project }) =>  {
              const title = project.title; 
              const description = project.description;
              const slug = project.slug;
              const imageData = project.image.childImageSharp.fluid;

              return (
                <ProjectPreview
                    title={title}
                    description={description}
                    slug={slug}
                    imageData={imageData}
                />
                );
              })}
          </div>
      </Layout> 
    );
};

export default Project
```

`/gatsby-node.js`

```
const { createPage } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter}) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    const result = await graphql(`
        {
            allProjectsJson {
                edges {
                    node {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }      
    `)
    if (result.error) {
        reporter.panic('there was an error in the projects template');
        return;
    }

    const projects = result.data.allProjectsJson.edges;

    projects.forEach(({ node: project }) => {
        const slug = project.slug;

        actions.createPage({
            path: `/${slug}/`,
            component: require.resolve('./src/templates/project.js'),
            context: { slug }
            });
        }
    );


    const blogTemplate = require.resolve('./src/templates/blog.js')
    const res = await graphql(`
    query {
        allContentfulBlogPost {
            edges {
                node {
                    slug
                }
              }
          }
        }  
    `);

    res.data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.forEach((edge) => {
            createPage({
                component: blogTemplate,
                path: `/blog/${edge.node.slug}`,
                context: {
                    slug: edge.node.slug
                }
            })
        })
}
```

`src/projects.json`

```
[
{
    "title": "css grid",
    "slug": "css-grid",
    "url": "https://example.com/",
    "image": "./images/rings.jpg",
    "description": "css grid layout"
},
{
    "title": "html email",
    "slug": "html-email",
    "url": "https://example.com/",
    "image": "./images/rings.jpg",
    "description": "html email example one"
}
]
```

Any help appreciated

UPDATE: After running a `find ./ -type f -exec grep -il "gatsby-focus-wrapper" {} \;` command suggested by @Maciek, got this output:

```
Linards:portfolio Berzins$ find ./ -type f -exec grep -il "gatsby-focus-wrapper" {} \;
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/static-entry.js
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/root.js
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/navigation.js
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/__tests__/__snapshots__/static-entry.js.snap
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/commonjs/static-entry.js
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/commonjs/root.js
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/commonjs/navigation.js
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/commonjs/production-app.js
.//node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/production-app.js
.//.cache/static-entry.js
.//.cache/root.js
.//.cache/navigation.js
.//.cache/__tests__/__snapshots__/static-entry.js.snap
.//.cache/commonjs/static-entry.js
.//.cache/commonjs/root.js
.//.cache/commonjs/navigation.js
.//.cache/commonjs/production-app.js
.//.cache/production-app.js
.//src/styles/index.scss
.//src/styles/portfolios.scss
```

Comment: If you look to the path specified in the error, it's cache folder. 

Maybe try to clean it with command *rm -rf .cache*

Afterwards if problem still persist, try to grep all files for the given class: *grep -r "gatsby-focus-wrapper"* to find where this code might be.

Please remember to execute given commands in correct path.

Comment: The error says the way you are importing `ProjectTemplate` is wrong in `app.js`. Did you check that ?

Comment: just posted an update @Maciek Is it a normal practice to remove any linking to `gatsby-focus-wrapper` in these files? Clearing cache does not work at all, tried that couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually comes from a bad importation module, such as import a module by default but it is not exported as a default component. In your case, in your `ProjectTemplate` component, you are importing: `import Layout from '../styles/Layout.scss'` which is a `.scss` file as a React component (`<Layout>`).

Without knowing the other components, I guess that your `<Layout>` is the default provided by Gatsby so, that path should point to it.